# How to extend ELO rating?

Tags: php, algorithm

In my soccer league Im using (where users play with teams) ELO rating. Everything works fine. I need advice on how to extend the formula to reflect the addition of the coefficient and power of the team players. (Teams have the power 1 to 10, 1 = the weakest team, 10 strongest team).

### For example:

The coefficient of domestic players is 1000, the coefficient of visiting players is 1000, the importance of constant event 32, the result of 1:0

Home player gets +16, -16 Visiting player.

And now incorporate the strength of the team (for example, power 10/6) and the result should be something like this ->  +12 / -12 = stronger player with a stronger team won.

I do not know how to edit. Thank you.

ELO RATING FORMULA = http://www.eloratings.net/system.html

Sorry for my bad english.

=========================================================================

## NEW EDIT and ANSWER FOR UR comment

Interesting idea, but not entirely accurate. I will try to demonstrate on a small example:

player1: spinning_plate (1000 elo points)
player2: Kcko (1000 elo points)

### example:

spinning_plate Kcko defeats (eg 1:0), they get points +15 / -15 -> this is still fine, but now we include the power of teams

improvements:
spinning_plate plays for FC Barcelona (Force 10), defeating Kcko (weaker team plays for AS Monaco for example, force 7), spinning_plate received less than 15 points (because they had the advantage of a better team. ELO points of both players are the same but the strength of their teams not).

Do you understand the essence of the problem?

Players play for different teams with different power and this should be included in the function ELO :)

Its taken from real formula ( http://www.eloratings.net/system.html )
I need to add strength by authentically to formula (s1 and s2)

```
$k1 - elo points of player 1
$k2 - elo points of player 2
$konstanta = weight constant for the tournament played
$g1 = goals for player 1
$g2 = goals for player 2
$s1 = new my own constant = strenght of team of player 1
$s2 = new my own constant = strenght of team of player 2



function elo($k1, $k2, $konstanta = 0, $g1, $g2, $s1 = 0, $s2 = 0)
{


    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    //debug($arg_list

    $s1 = (int) $s1;
    $s2 = (int) $s2;

    $G_rozdil = Abs($g1 - $g2); // golovy rozdil 
    // Konstanta za vysledek hry
    if ($g1 > $g2)  
        $W = 1;
    elseif ($g1 == $g2)
        $W = 0.5;
    else
        $W = 0;  

    // Rating puvodni, za domaciho
    $Ro = $koeficient1; 
    $K  = $konstanta; // Zakladni konstanta pro hrane zapasy, cim dulezitejsi turnaj tim vyssi 20-60
                        // a dale se navysuje o urcity koeficient pocitaneho z rozdilu golu
    if ($G_rozdil==2) 
        $K=$K*1.5;
    elseif ($G_rozdil==3) 
        $K=$K*1.75;
    elseif ($G_rozdil>3) 
        $K=$K*((1.75+(($G_rozdil-3)/8)));


    $dr = $k1 - $k2; // 100 zvyhodnuje hosta , protoze hraje venku 


    // Konecny result
    $Rn = $Ro + $K * ($W - $We);


    // To dostanou domaci
    $Body1 = Round($Rn - $Ro);

    // Toto hoste
    $Body2 = $Body1 * -1;

    if ($Body1 == 0 || $Body2 == 0)
    {
        return array(0, 0);
    }

    return array($Body1, $Body2);
}
```

Comment: I'm confused - the strength of the team should be reflected in the ELO rating, ELO already balances the points given so that if a strong team beats a weak team, they get less points than if they beat a similarlly rated team

Comment: I explained it badly (and my poor English ...)

The real user (player) plays with a virtual team with the power of 1 to 10 against another user with a virtual team (soccer team)

The user has the ELO rating. The team has only the power of 1 to 10 And I need this power to the final scores also reflected.

The actual link http://fifa.gameway.cz/grt (not in English)

Comment: Your English is fine and clear to me, I was just clarifying, see my answer/thoughts below

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to do in this situation is translate the computers' strengths to an preliminary ELO rating.

I take my example from Chess and internet chess servers like [FICS](http://freechess.org).   When a computer plays, it's treated just like a human opponent - it gets a preliminary rating and is later rated based on whether it wins or loses against human and computer opponents.

You might have a bootstrapping problem, though, if you don't have enough players in that strong computers might not be able to get a decent rating because all the other players are weak.  In this case, you could simply map your 1-10 on the range of MIN_RATING- MAX_RATING.  MAX_RATING is not actually the max rating and MIN_RATING probably shouldn't be 0. ELO is a relative ranking system, the absolute numbers mean nothing, so you might choose them according to your player base.   In chess, the higher rating is around 27-2800 for Grandmasters and the lowest are around the 400s newbies that stick around but don't improve.

The main point here is that if you give them a preliminary rating, over time they will move towards their 'true rating' because they will play games against players and move accordingly.

***EDIT***

Why not just scale the weight constant based on the team differential? How about something like this:

```
K*(F(9-abs(s1-s2)))
```

where F(x) is a [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) or even just a linear function [0...9]->[1...0}.  This means a team with equal ratings gets the full constant and teams with bigger differences scale down to zero or whatever you choose.

I don't know if I agree that this calculation is the best way to approach this problem.  The statistics of ELO might not apply if you use it this way, but I don't have a better suggestion without doing more research.

Comment: Thx for reply, i added advanced information about it in first comment. Thanks for trying

Comment: "Why not just scale the weight constant based on the team differential"

Hard to explain it. Many users have a variety of competitions for different teams and I want to take into account not only the skill level of users but also the power of the team ... Thx for your interest :-) I find your idea useful and I think they think of how to do it